# Diferença entre ":" e "." nos métodos de uma tabela Lua

Tags: funções, lua, operadores, sintaxe

Me deparei com duas declarações diferentes que me deixaram confuso.

```
obj = {}

function obj.Create(name)

end


function obj:GoGoGo(name)

end
```

Qual é a diferença da função declarada com o `.` (ponto)  e `:` (dois pontos)?

Comment: A pessoa que deu -1 deve fragar pra caramba de `Lua` ;)

Comment: Deve ser seu o fã :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O primeiro é o operador de membros, ele só separa a quem a função pertence.

O segundo é um açúcar sintático, é o mesmo que:

```
function obj.GoGoGo(self, name)

end
```

Então ele só coloca um parâmetro a mais para receber o objeto e dar uma notação mais OOP para a linguagem. O mesmo que tantas outras linguagens fazem de forma um pouco mais automática.

Chamada:

```
var x = obj
x.GoGoGo(10)
```

Na verdade a chamada será:

```
obj.GoGoGo(x, 10)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/ObjectNotation.lua).

Para saber um pouco mais [sobre o funcionamento do pseudo OOP de Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html).

Answer (score 4):

O "dois-pontos" serve para chamar `self` como primeiro parâmetro da função.

Logo `obj:GoGoGo(name)` deve ser a mesma coisa que `obj.GoGoGo(obj, name)`.

---

<sup>Vi isso numa resposta do SO um tempo atrás, mas não achei ela.</sup>